# Internet Explorer Developer tools CSS issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Can anyone tell me what the squiggly lines underneath the css property mean (pictured below)? 
I would assume they mean that the browser doesn't understand what the properties are but in another project the same properties work as they should.

[image: clip of Internet Explorer Developer Tools Styles]

Comment: is the display:flex; value also declared or not overwritten elsewhere , else on their owns, these are useless but valid

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the errors are stemming from, but flex is extremely questionable in IE 11. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: display: flex; is not overwritten and doesn't have those same squiggly lines as flex-direction and align-items. I'm at a loss why this would be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally didn't think of this until today, but the reason why the browser was not recognizing the css properties is because the website was being forced into compatibility mode with the following meta tag.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

fixed that and now it works as expected.